# Bitmaps - getting very large values

Tags: android, bitmap, grayscale

I am using bitmaps in Android. As I am converting to grayscale, I should expect a value between 0 and 255 for each pixel. But for the pixels, I am getting some of them as 0 and the others as very large values. I dont know why. WHy am I not getting values in the range [0,255]? How do I get it?

My code is:

```
//Converting to grayscale
                        int width, height;
                        height = mybitmap.getHeight();
                        width = mybitmap.getWidth();    

                        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
                        cm.setSaturation(0);
                        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
                        paint.setColorFilter(f);
                        c.drawBitmap(mybitmap, 0, 0, paint);                
                        //Done bmpgrayscale is the grayscale image formed
                        Toast toast23=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Grayscale made", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                        toast23.show();
                        for (int i=0;i<210;i++){
                            for (int j=0;j<170;j++){

                                    Log.d("gray value is=", String.valueOf(bmpGrayscale.getPixel(i, j)));

                            }
                        }
```

A part of the output is:

```
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 0
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 83886079
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 317846001
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 602992880
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 669772779
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 904719596
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 971894253
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.022: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
12-07 23:14:28.052: D/gray value is=(958): 1223552493
```

Please help. I am using this to convert my view to bitmap followed by the conversion of the bitmap to grayscale.

EDIT

```
//Converting to grayscale
                        int width, height;
                        height = mybitmap.getHeight();
                        width = mybitmap.getWidth();    

                        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
                        cm.setSaturation(0);
                        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
                        paint.setColorFilter(f);
                        c.drawBitmap(mybitmap, 0, 0, paint);                
                        //Done bmpgrayscale is the grayscale image formed
                        Toast toast23=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Grayscale made", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                        toast23.show();
                        for (int i=0;i<210;i++){
                            for (int j=0;j<170;j++){
                                    int a=bmpGrayscale.getPixel(i, j);
                                    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                                  //b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // optional, the initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN.
                                    b.putInt(a  );

                                    byte[] result = b.array();                                      
                                    Log.d("gray value is=", String.valueOf((int)result[0]));

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: I'm confused why you are expecint 0-255 for returns. The large values make more sense if you do a conversion to hex: 83886079 = 4FFFFFFF. 1223552493 = 48EDEDED. Notice how the last 3 sets of bytes are always equal? (grayscale values would always have RGB equal)

Comment: @TheCapn Okay. But I want the values in the range [0,255] for further operations. What do I do? How do I convert the values to that range?

Comment: Convert the int value to a series of bytes, take the last 8 bytes and convert them back to int? You'll have something ranged 0-255 from that (0-FF hex is same as 0-255 decimal)

Comment: @TheCapn Last 8 bytes or last 8 bits? Can you give me a code for that?

Comment: Bits I'm sorry. I'll put together some code and post in a few minutes

Comment: @TheCapn It works, but I am getting good values only with the default color of the gesture overlay view....with black and all, i get negative grayscale values. Please explain. I have added the new code in the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting negative values, might be an overflow thing? Here's what I did

```
int value = getLastBytes(1223552493); //Prints 237, the dec value of ED 

public int getLastBytes(long original) {
String hexBytes = Long.toHexString(original);
return Integer.parseInt(hexBytes.substring(hexBytes.length()-2),16);
}
```

In your case you could probably call it as so:

```
Log.d("gray value is=", getLastBytes(bmpGrayscale.getPixel(i, j)));
```